# Xamarin Forms: Debugger leaves the async method without awaiting

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm getting started with XamarinForms, and I've encountered a *strange* problem.

The app flow is like this:

- From a page *(NewExpensePage.cs)* I open a modal (push async) for a Create operation
- Page has BindingContext with a ViewModel *(ExpenseViewModel.cs)*
- A button command is connected with a Command (SaveExpenseCommand) in ViewModel class, that will call a method in a Service (IBTService.cs), which in turn will issue a HttpPost request.

Page Code Behind:

```
public partial class NewExpensePage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly ExpenseViewModel viewModel;

    public NewExpensePage(int currentGroupId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new ExpenseViewModel(currentGroupId);
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
        // let this page know save op has completed, and the close the modal
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ExpenseViewModel>(this, "save-completed", async (i) => { await Navigation.PopModalAsync(); });
    }
}
```

ViewModel code:

```
public class ExpenseViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    /* ... */
    public Command SaveExpenseCommand { get; set; }
    private readonly int CurrentGroupId;
    public ExpenseViewModel(int selectedGroupId)
    {
        CurrentGroupId = selectedGroupId;
        this.LoadCategoriesCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadCategories());
        this.SaveExpenseCommand = new Command(async () => await SaveExpense());
    }

    async Task SaveExpense()
    {
        Item.ExpenseCategoryId = SelectedCategory.Id;
        await IBTService.SaveExpense(Item);
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "save-completed");
    }
}
```

And finally the method in Service Code (IBTService.cs):

```
    public async Task<bool> SaveExpense(Expense model)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(api);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

            var dbModel = new ApiExpense
            {
                Amount = model.Amount,
                Date = model.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                ExpenseCategoryId = model.ExpenseCategoryId,
                Description = model.Description
            };
            // HERE: Debugger runs out to caller method (back in view model) without waiting for this to complete
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/Expenses/PostExpense", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbModel)));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return true; //temp solution
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

The problem in here starts with `var response = await httpClient.PostAsync...` in the final code part, where debugger jumps out of execution as soon as it *executes* this line, without ***awaiting** for this result to complete.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try this, `await httpClient.PostAsync("api/Expenses/PostExpense", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));` You may also want to try and add you full path to the `PostAsync`...

Comment: No difference, I even tried with a working get request from another view. The api is ok. I've probably misused some ground rule on the way mvvm works with async/awaits...

Comment: Did it return true or false in method SaveExpense? Await won't block the program and it will continue execution when that task completes. As soon as it executes this line, the default behavior is back to viewModel and execute other codes, once the response comes back,  it will execute the code after this line and then return true or false.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ and Jack Hua you are both right.

The problem appears to be with the http call and not the architecture. Specifically because I treated the call as a fire-and-forget situation, as I closed the pagemodal as soon as the control was returned from issuing the http call.

I modified the code to return an error msg and response status, and removed the part where redirecting and here's about a model state validation 
 http://prntscr.com/nlf093

Thanks both of you guys.

Comment: thank you for all the inputs, helped me with my challenge